# Return array from an object

Tags: jquery, jackson

**Hi all,
please could you help me?**

I need to return an array based on the key value "currentAsin" from the object "dimensionValuesDisplayData". The values are variable, of course. p.s. raw Jackson jq

example: for "B0172AFA1E" is a result: `["1 Rotolo", "99017 50mm x 12mm"]`

```
{
  "currentAsin": "B0172AFA1E",
  "dimensionValuesDisplayData": {
    "B0172ACN0A": [
      "2 Rotoli",
      "11352 25mm x 54mm"
    ],
    "B0172ADETO": [
      "3 Rotoli",
      "11355 19mm x 51mm"
    ],
    "B0172AFA1E": [
      "1 Rotolo",
      "99017 50mm x 12mm"
    ],
    "B0172AF7BC": [
      "10 Rotoli",
      "99015 54mm x 70mm"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library, Jackson is a Java library. Which language are you actually using?

Comment: For JavaScript, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.